# Overlap label on imageview inside uistackview ios

Tags: uiview, overlap, uistackview, uiview-hierarchy

I would like to **overlap two views** (one view on top of each other) **inside uistackview** . My objective is to display initials of username on top of his image. The image size is constant and the initial label should be in centre of image view

I have a uitableviewcell on which other labels and buttons are also organized

here is the view hierarchy.

[image: View Hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this in following way and it works

Excluded the view which I wanted to overlap from UIStackView

Make that Label to align with following constraints

*Center Vertically with ImageView 
Center Horizontally with ImageView 
Equal Widhts with ImageView
Equal Heights with ImageView*

[image: Constraints of Label to UIImageView]

[image: Arrangement of StackView]

Answer (score 0):

To overlap views use -ve spacing in StackView